# Open Graphs (author) não é inserido em página

Tags: html-meta-tag

Possuo dois sites de nichos diferentes.
O que acontece é o seguinte: quando faço um post no Facebook, colando o link de um post, em um dos sites aparece o "BY Felipe Viero Goulart", show de bola, é isso que eu quero. Só que eu gostaria que isso aparecesse nos dois site.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dois foram desenvolvidos com Wordpress com o tema Sahifa. Ambos possuem a mesma configuração no Yoast, e a parte de Autor no Wordpress está igual também.

Tentei incluir manualmente:

```
<meta property="article:publisher" content="http://facebook.com/yourpagelink" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="<?php the_permalink ();?>" />
```

Usei permalink pra pegar a URL atual.

E nem assim foi.

O que pode ser?

Comment: Hint - Os headers estão diferentes: O de Better Call Saul Brasil possui o indicador 'Published by Felipe Viero Goulart'.

Comment: Mas e por que não aparece na hora de compartilhar o post? - da mesma forma que é feito no Neil Gaiman Brasil

Comment: Passe por aqui algumas vezes: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ . Á vezes precisamos removar o cache do facebook em relação aos dados `open graph` de uma app

Comment: Outra coisa que poderia fazer é `<meta name="author" content="NOME AUTOR">`, o facebook apanha este parametro também

Comment: Outra coisa que não sei se é suposto acontecer, não tem a haver com o problema mas é um reparo: http://bettercallsaul.com.br/ dá modo de manutenção mas http://bettercallsaul.com.br/home já não, já se consegue ver tudo normalmente

Comment: Se tentou a solução da `<meta name="author"... Passe o site no https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ algumas vezes e veja se resulta

Comment: Eu passei pelo DEBUG, mas mesmo assim não resolveu. Eu gostaria que ele pegasse diretamente o meu perfil no Facebook, como faz no site Neil Gaiman.